# How can the commit stats show negative total line count?

Tags: git, github

I'm being curious here, it's not really knowledge I need to have, but out of curiosity, how come [github is showing for that project](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/cigale-timesheet/graphs/contributors) with a single contributor `535 commits / 35,625 ++ / 55,548 --`, so it looks like there were more lines removed than were added? I would expect lines added to be always a number greater or equal than lines removed?

Comment: Well thats because of the fact that you might have a file `A.c` which have 1.000 lines of code, and you delete those 1.000 lines and add just 50. So you have a commit with 1000 deletions and just 50 additions.

Comment: yes but first i had to add that `A.c` file in the repo right? So I would have `+1050 -1000`

Comment: Imagine the following: Add file `A.c` with 1000 lines. Commit(1000 additions), delete 1000 lines, commit(1000 deletions), add 50 lines, commit(50 additions)

Comment: and is that not `+1050 -1000`?

Comment: Well I am not sure if they are accumulated. For me its more like a counter, going up to 1000, down to -1000, up to 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out there was some confusion between me and the authors of other answers because I did not specify clearly enough that this repository has a single author. Once you take that into account it follows that the line count difference should be >=0 as I assumed.

And the reason of the issue is that, due to some misuse of `git` (maybe not configuring the author's email), some commits are marked as being from author `unknown`, and that unknown is also not displayed in the stats of the app as a different author, and his commits apparently not counted in the stats either.

Already the [first commit](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/cigale-timesheet/commit/4aa0e010bc52fce2d492e1879efe2a427c53e4e9) exhibits the problem, and some others later on.

Whether the author can fix those commits after they were pushed, to mark them as his, is probably the topic of another question.

Answer (score 1):

Why?

> I would expect lines added to be always a number greater or equal than lines removed

If you deleted a huge part of the file so those lines are removed. 
The numbers are very simple:

- How many lines were **added** (+)
- How how many were **deleted** (-)

Why cant the number be like this? The 2 numbers are not based one upon the other, they are pure accumulation of the total lines in all the committed files.

Comment: before I deleted the file I had to add it in the repo and that would also be counted in the stats?

Comment: You right, all your changes are counted. added + removed

Comment: so, my whole question is, how could i remove lines if I didn't add them beforehand? Hence how can the total be negative? I still don't get it.

Comment: Its simply sum of how many lines added vs deleted not how many lines of code the project has

Comment: let me explain:

Now in your repo you have file with 100 lines. you removed 5 lines and added 5 lines (different ones). the status will display +++++----- which stands for 5 added & 5 removed. There is no reference to the total number of lines in teh file

Comment: The numbers are reflecting the changes compared to the previous commit. type `git show` to view the changes

Comment: honestly I still don't get it. I would probably need an example of commit history to understand it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78284/discussion-between-codewizard-and-emmanuel-touzery).